# OneToMany relationship in Symfony3 and Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have one-to-many relationship, it's Currency with many Rates. So I define them as I read from manual:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="currency")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Currency{}

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="rate")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Rate
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="currency_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Currency", inversedBy="rate")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="currency_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $currency;

    /**
     * @param  Currency $currency
     * @return Rate
     */
    public function setCurrency(Currency $currency) : Rate
    {
        $this->currency = $currency;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Currency
     */
    public function getCurrency() : Currency
    {
        return $this->currency;
    }
}
```

But it seems I can't just assign Currency model to the property **$this->currency**, because Doctrine think it's some primitive like int, and just inserts {} into the query.

```
Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Currency could not be converted to string
```

If I change the field to **currency_id** and return int from getter - it's fine, but how could I in this case the the related Currency model (I mean **$rate->getCurrency()->something**)? Of course I can implement Currency::__toString but looks like awful idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `@ORM\Column` annotation:

```
 * @ORM\Column(name="currency_id", type="integer")
```

Doctrine will figure it out what should be the type of this column basing on `referencedColumnName` declared in `@ORM\JoinColumn`.

Comment: Thank you a lot. You saved my day =)